# How to send mail via java maven application

Tags: java, maven, class, email, send

I'm using maven to devlop an application, I'm using Eclipse as an IDE,
I'm running a Mapview Class as output,
My problem is how I send the output ( which is on Mapview Form) by mail?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should refine your question as it is very broad and not clear. Make sure you have read [ask] and edit your question. Maven as a build tool and eclipse as an IDE should not have a lot to do with sending mails. What are you referring to exactly with mapview? a website? a custom swing/awt component? android? Is your question about how to actually send an email or is it about accessing the mapviews data to make up the emails contents?

Comment: Hello, mapview is a class defined on my project,,
 and my question is how to send an email that cointans this output 
        I     mean what I runned

Answer (score 0):

Use javax mail for it. 
Encapsulate the output in a MimeMessage object and use javax.mail.Transport to send it.

```
public MimeMessage build() throws MessagingException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
    mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddressList);

    mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mimeMessage.setText(output);
    mimeMessage.saveChanges();
    return mimeMessage;
}
```

Use javax.mail.Transport to send it.

```
Transport.send(mimeMessage);
```